# How to access EventGrid trigger Event properties in Azure functions input bindings

Tags: python, azure-functions, azure-eventgrid

I want to pull in cosmos documents into my azure function based on contents of eventgrid events that it triggers on (python worker runtime). Is it possible to do this?

I have below function.json:

```
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "type": "eventGridTrigger",
      "name": "event",
      "direction": "in"
    },
    {
      "name": "documents",
      "type": "cosmosDB",
      "databaseName": "Metadata",
      "collectionName": "DataElementMappings",
      "sqlQuery" : "SELECT * from c where c.id = {subject}",
      "connectionStringSetting": "MyCosmosDBConnectionString",
      "direction": "in"
  }
  ]
}
```

I want to use properties of the event in the query for the cosmos input binding. I tried it with subject here. It fails with:

[6/4/2020 5:34:45 PM] System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: Functions.orch_taskchecker. System.Private.CoreLib: The given key 'subject' was not present in the dictionary.

So I am not using the right key name. The only key I got to work is {data} but unfortunately I was not able to access any properties inside the event data using the syntax {data.property} as it says in the docs. I would expect all of the event grid schema keys to be available to use in other bindings since an event is a JSON payload. I got none of them to work, e.g. eventTime, event_type, topic, etc.

Since I saw an example of the same idea for storage queues and they used for example {Queue.id} I tried things like {Event.subject}, {EventGridEvent.subject} all to no avail.

Nowhere in the docs can I find samples of event grid trigger data being used in other bindings. Can this be achieved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For *EventGridTrigger* (**C# script**) can be used for input bindings a custom data object of the *EventGridEvent* class.

The following example shows a blob input bindings for event storage account:

```
 {
    "bindings": [
    {
      "type": "eventGridTrigger",
      "name": "eventGridEvent",
      "direction": "in"
    },
    {
      "type": "blob",
      "name": "body",
      "path": "{data.url}",
      "connection": "rk2018ebstg_STORAGE",
      "direction": "in"
    }
  ],
  "disabled": false
}
```

Note, that only a property from the *data* object can be referenced.

Comment: Thanks a lot for confirming you cannot reference eventgrid schema properties like subject or topic. Also the properties within data I cannot reference. I have a data payload in the event with properties a and b:

"data" : {"a": 1234, "b": 45667}

[6/5/2020 7:15:23 AM] System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: Functions.orch_taskchecker. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error while accessing 'a': property doesn't exist.

So I don't seem to be able to access properties within data but at least it recognizes there is a data key there.

Comment: In *C# script* function there is no problem to access a data object properties like your payload example. Probably, the python doesn't support it.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I think it is not supported. Total bummer if I cannot use the bindings. Accessing the event properties from within python code is no problem by the way but I would have preferred not having to do cosmos queries in the function code.

Comment: Can anyone confirm that python does not support accessing the `data` object?

Answer (score -1):

There is the event.get_json() method that you can use to access the data field in the python code, I did not look at the bindings

Comment: Sorry, I missed the request for more info. As main I have **def main(event: func.EventGridEvent):
   event_data = parseEventData(event.get_json())**, translating the event to a dictionary that you can read: **def parseEventData(event_data: dict):
    attr_value = event_data.get('attributeKey', 'default-value');**